# Declaration of a button process

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to understand the process of the declaration of a button.

```
@interface MerdaViewController : UIViewController{    
    IBOutlet UIButton *button;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

@end
```

Why do we need those steps?

Is it always required?

Thank you so much.

Alex.

Comment: So you think I don't understand the French word "Merda" meaning "Shitty"? Nice try. :-)

Comment: @H2CO3 LOL +1 for this comment

Comment: I just wanted to name it as a not useful function in my code and I forgot to change the name to post my question... Sorry. And, it's not in french it's in catalan ;) (the same word for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To create a button outlet you just need this line.**

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

**To create button action**

```
-(IBAction)doSomething:(id)sender;
```

**Just like to add another point:**

Outlets should generally be weak/assign, except for those from File’s Owner to top-level objects in a nib file (or, in iOS, a storyboard scene) which should be strong/retain

Comment: Unless it's the top level object of a nib that you are loading yourself, usually it's `assign` for IBOutlets - preferably `weak` with ARC

Answer (score 0):

1. at least in relatively new versions of XCode, you don't need to declare that instance variable. It's automatically taken care of.
2. you need the `@property` so you can call `self.button` and do whatever you like to it. `IBOutlet` tells XCode it's an element in your interface builder, so you can hook it up with that visual button you added to IB.
3. more often than not I find myself actually declaring an `-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender;` rather than an `IBOutlet`. This way when you tap that button, the `IBAction` method is automatically triggered.

Comment: There are plenty of instances where you'd declare an `IBOutlet` instead of just an `IBAction`.  As just a simple example, perhaps the enabled state of a button is dependent on other actions the user is taking on the screen, at which point you'd need a reference to that button to set `button.enabled = NO;`

Comment: that's absolutely right. whenever you want a reference to `self.button` you declare an `IBOutlet`. But if it's just a pretty standard thing then simply an `IBAction` will do the trick.